# Ajax returns undefined objects in the list in asp.net

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a web application in asp.net where in the index page I implemented an AJAX call to get the list of defect object and populate it into the HTML table.

I have written a method in the controller "GetDefect" which return the list of defects in JSON format.But the result is ended up as undefined when I get it on the Javascript side.

I have spent hours and still cannot find the solution. I had also searched other StackOverflow questions but could not help it.

**The Model Class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcApplication3.Models
{
    public class Defect
    {
        private string ID;
        private DateTime date_created;
        private string updated_by;
        private string created_by;
        private string description;




    public Defect(string ID, DateTime date_created,string updated_by,string ,created_by,string description)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.date_created = date_created;
        this.updated_by = updated_by;
        this.created_by = created_by;
        this.description = description;
    }


}
```

}

**The controller**

```
[HttpGet]
        public  JsonResult  GetDefects()
        {
           IList<Defect> dataList = new List<Defect>();
           dataList.Add(new Defect("eththeth",DateTime.Now.Date,"ergerger","ergergerger","ergerg"));
           dataList.Add(new Defect("wefwefwef", DateTime.Now.Date, "wew44r3", "gbnvfbnvbn v", "gbndfgnbfgnf"));

           return Json(new { dataList = dataList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

**The JS file**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    GetFoodDetails();
});


function GetFoodDetails() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "Home/GetDefects",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.dataList);
            applychanges(data);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert('eror');
        }
    });

}

function applychanges(result) {
    console.log(result);
    var html = '';
    $.each(result, function (key, item) {
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td>' + item.ID + '</td>';
        html += '<td>' + item.description + '</td>';
        html += '<td>' + item.defect_status + '</td>';
        html += '<td>' + item.date_created + '</td>';
        html += '<td>' + item.created_by + '</td>';
        html += '<td>' + item.location_lang + '</td>';
        html += '<td>' + item.location_long + '</td>';
        html += '<td><a href="#" onclick="return getbyID(' + item.ID + ')">Edit</a> | <a href="#" onclick="Delele(' + item.ID + ')">Delete</a></td>';
        html += '</tr>';
    });
    $('.tbody').html(html);
}
```

**HTML (the table)**

```
<table  class="table table-bordered table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Date Raised</th>
              <th>Date Due</th>
              <th>Defect Status</th>
              <th>Defect Remarks</th>
              <th>Langitude</th>
              <th>Longitude</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
            <tbody class="tbody">
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

[image: two muppets]

If anyone knows , please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the JSON as received by the browser. You should be able to see it in the dev tools *Network* tab, or if not, add `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` in your Ajax success handler.

Comment: Because they all all `private` fields - make them public properties.

Comment: @StephenMuecke It works !! 
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private fields are not serialized by the `JavaScriptSerializer`. Make them public properties in your model.

```
public class Defect
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_created  { get; set; }
    .... // etc
```

Your method is also expecting the collection so it should be

```
success: function (data) {
    applychanges(data.dataList); // change
```

Alternatively, change the controller method to just return the collection

```
return Json(dataList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try by replacing the GetFoodDetails with the following.

```
function GetFoodDetails() {
  $.get('/Home/GetDefects', null, function (data) {
        $.each(data.dataList, function (i, dl) {
            alert(dl.ID);
        });
    });

}
```

and if it works please let me know and there is no change in your controller action method code.

Also you can try this one also

```
    function GetFoodDetails() {
$.ajaxSetup({
            async: false
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Home/GetDetails',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.dataList);
            }
        });
}
```